# Creating an Observable that binds to an existing function

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ng2-file-upload

I've been trying to bind the `onCompleteItem` array function from the `ng2-file-upload` package to an RxJS Observable method that I can subscribe to.

Here is function I'm talking about:

```
onCompleteItem(item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders): any;
```

..which in use is *almost the same* as:

```
onCompleteItem(item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any)
```

Here's the relevant parts from **MyComponent**, which is currently working:

```
imageArray: Image[] = [];

uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({
  url: '/api/FileUpload'
});

ngOnInit() {

  this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response);
    data.forEach(x => {
      console.log(x);
      this.imageArray.push(x);
    }
    this.uploader.removeFromQueue(item);
  };

}
```

My attempt at binding this into an Observable was through the use of the RxJS `bindCallback` function:

```
bindCallback(this.uploader.onCompleteItem, {item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any})().pipe(
  tap((item, response) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response);
    this.uploader.removeFromQueue(item);
    const images = data.map(x => console.log(x) );
    this.imageArray.push(...images);
  })
).subscribe();
```

This does not work, because of a few type/syntax errors. Does anyone have any good suggestions on how to get this rewritten as a bound Observable function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindCallback` wraps a function that's called whenever the observable is subscribed to, e.g. `getJSON(url, callback)`. You're trying to use it just by passing the `callback` parameter.

Instead you can try the `fromEventPattern` function, which allows you to specify via its two parameters how you register the event handler, and also unregister.

```js
const {fromEventPattern} = rxjs;

const uploader = {
  upload() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.onCompleteItem) this.onCompleteItem('arg 1', 'arg 2');
    }, 1000);
  }
};

const source = fromEventPattern(handler => uploader.onCompleteItem = handler, _ => uploader.onCompleteItem = null);

source.subscribe(([arg1, arg2]) => console.log(arg1, arg2));
uploader.upload();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.4/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a real journey.. But I hope this answer gives some users new insight.

Here's a few solutions that worked that I went from initially, with the last solution listed being what I ended up implementing.

**Initial solution:**

```
const obs = new Observable<{ item: FileItem, response: string }>(sub => {
  this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: FileItem, response: string) => sub.next({ item, response });
  return () => this.uploader.onCompleteItem = undefined;
});

bindCallback((x: (item: FileItem, response: string) => any) => this.uploader.onCompleteItem = x)()
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.onDestroySubj),
    tap(([item, response]) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(response);
      this.imageArray.push(...data );
      this.uploader.removeFromQueue(item);
    })
  ).subscribe();
```

The only problem with the solution above is that `bindCallBack` only fires once.

**A More Refined Solution:**

```
Observable.create((sub: Subscriber<[FileItem, string]>) => {
  this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: FileItem, response: string) => sub.next([item, response]);
  return () => this.uploader.onCompleteItem = undefined;
}).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.onDestroySubj),
  tap(([item, response]) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response);
    this.imageArray.push(...data );
    this.uploader.removeFromQueue(item);
  })
).subscribe();
```

This got me thinking.. And I considered using `fromEvent` because it subscribes to jQuery actions and browser events, but not unless a wrapper is written. Which is what led me to my final solution, using `fromEventPattern`:

**Final Solution:** (full code)

```
ngOnInit() {
  fromEventPattern<Parameters<FileUploader['onCompleteItem']>>(x => this.uploader.onCompleteItem = x).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.onDestroySubj),
    tap(([item, response]) => {
      this.imageArray = this.imagesSubject.getValue();
      const data = JSON.parse(response);
      this.imageArray.push(...data );
      this.uploader.removeFromQueue(item);

      // because I'm using a Subject
      this.imagesSubject.next(this.imageArray);
    })
  ).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.onDestroySubj.next();
}
```